# PHP Foreach a function with a return and insert into db

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I have created a code that inserts odds into database from an XML file from unibet, and it is working pretty well, but instead of inserting all odds from the 100 games that I have setup, it inserts only 2 bets, I know it is hooked to the function `dec2frac`, because when I remove that it will insert every bet offer into correct row, but then I can't calculate the odds and I will then need to manually insert them.

the whole PHP is

```
 <?php


$xml=simplexml_load_file("unibetapi") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "password", "db") or die ("ERROR: Cannot connect");

/* Assumes that the number of IDs = number of customers */
$size = sizeOf($xml->id);
$i = 5; //index


/* Add each customer to the database, See how we reference it as    $xml->ENTITY[INDEX] */
while($i != $size) 
{

    print_r($xml->participant);
    echo $xml->participant; //Test
    foreach($xml->betoffers as $betoffer) //Extract the Array Values by using Foreach Loop
    {
         //Function to convert from decimels to fraction
    function dec2frac($dec) { 

        $decBase = --$dec; 

        $div = 1; 

        do { 

            $div++; 

            $dec = $decBase * $div; 

        } while (intval($dec) != $dec); 

        if ($dec % $div == 0) { 
            $dec = $dec / $div; 
            $div = $div / $div; 
        } 

        return $dec.' '.$div; 

    } 

        //Label of the bet
        $criteria = ($betoffer->criterion->label);
        //Criteria of the bet - Home,Draw, Away etc
        $crit = ($criteria);  

        //BET Participant
        $string = ($betoffer->outcomes->participant);

        //Convert odds to fracture
        $bet = ($string); 
        $number = ($betoffer->outcomes->odds);
        $format_number = number_format("$number" , 0, ',', '.');
        $decimal = ($format_number);

        //Explode Fracture
        $pizza  = dec2frac($decimal);
        $pieces = explode(" ", $pizza);



        echo $bet;


    //$sql = "INSERT INTO xf_nflj_sportsbook_event (event_id, category_id, user_id, username, title, description, event_status, date_create, date_open, date_close, date_settle, date_edit, event_timezone, wagers_placed, amount_staked, amount_paidout, likes, like_users, view_count, outcome_count, comment_count, thread_id, prefix_id, last_comment_date, limit_wagers_single_outcome) VALUES ('$event->id',2,1,'tipstr', '$event->name', '$event->group', 'open', 1517755596,1517755596,1517761200,1517761200,0,'Europe/London', 0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)";
    $sql = "INSERT INTO xf_nflj_sportsbook_outcome (`outcome_id`, `event_id`, `outcome_date`, `outcome_date_edited`, `outcome_title`, `outcome_current_odds_against`, `outcome_current_odds_for`, `outcome_max_wagers`, `outcome_min_wager_amount`, `outcome_max_wager_amount`, `outcome_pays`, `outcome_wagers_placed`, `outcome_amount_staked`, `outcome_amount_paidout`, `outcome_settled`, `outcome_date_settled`) VALUES ('$betoffer->id', '$betoffer->eventId', 1518116479, 0, '$bet - $crit ', '$pieces[0]', '$pieces[1]', 0, 10, 0, 'N', 0, 0, '0.00', 'N', 0)";

    mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die ("ERROR: " .mysqli_error($connection) . " (query was $sql)");

    $i++; //increment index


    }



}


mysqli_close($connection);
```

Comment: Just a suggestion, but you should take the function declaration outside of the loop so it doesn't get continually redefined. Just place it at the top of the script.

Comment: I have done that in the updated version, but it still happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Move the `$i` index out of `foreach` block and change initial declaration of `$i`

It seems the increment logic is not correct.

You have to increment the index `$i` outside the `foreach` block since the counter is for the `while` block.

Since it is incremented inside the `foreach` loop, `$i` value gets incremented multiple times according to the number of the elements present in `betoffers`.

Also you have declared the initial value of `$i` to 5. Remove it as well.

Comment: I moved the $I++ out of the foreach, but it is still just adding 2 items. Any ideas?

Comment: @Tipstr It must be something to do with your core logic. Anyways, if my answer helped you in any way, consider marking it as accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that unibet also has fractures, so I modded the script and now it works 100%. Here is the end result.

```
  <?php


$xml=simplexml_load_file("unibet_api_xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "password", "db") or die ("ERROR: Cannot connect");

/* Assumes that the number of IDs = number of customers */
$size = sizeOf($xml->betOfferResponse);
$i = 2; //index




//Explode fraction



/* Add each customer to the database, See how we reference it as    $xml->ENTITY[INDEX] */
while($i != $size) 
{


    include'defrac.php';
    foreach($xml->betoffers as $betoffer) //Extract the Array Values by using Foreach Loop
    {

    //Convert odds to fraction

      /*  $number = ($betoffer->outcomes->odds);
        $format_number = number_format("$number" , 0, ',', '.');
        $decimal = ($format_number);*/

        $pizza  = ($betoffer->outcomes->oddsFractional);
        $pieces = explode("/", $pizza);
        echo $pieces[0];
        echo $pieces[1];

        //Label of the bet
        $criteria = ($betoffer->criterion->label);
        //Criteria of the bet - Home,Draw, Away etc
        $crit = ($criteria);  

        //BET Participant
        $string = ($betoffer->outcomes->participant);
        $bet = ($string); 






        //$sql = "INSERT INTO xf_nflj_sportsbook_event (event_id, category_id, user_id, username, title, description, event_status, date_create, date_open, date_close, date_settle, date_edit, event_timezone, wagers_placed, amount_staked, amount_paidout, likes, like_users, view_count, outcome_count, comment_count, thread_id, prefix_id, last_comment_date, limit_wagers_single_outcome) VALUES ('$event->id',2,1,'tipstr', '$event->name', '$event->group', 'open', 1517755596,1517755596,1517761200,1517761200,0,'Europe/London', 0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)";
       $sql = "INSERT INTO xf_nflj_sportsbook_outcome (`outcome_id`, `event_id`, `outcome_date`, `outcome_date_edited`, `outcome_title`, `outcome_current_odds_against`, `outcome_current_odds_for`, `outcome_max_wagers`, `outcome_min_wager_amount`, `outcome_max_wager_amount`, `outcome_pays`, `outcome_wagers_placed`, `outcome_amount_staked`, `outcome_amount_paidout`, `outcome_settled`, `outcome_date_settled`) VALUES ('$betoffer->id', '$betoffer->eventId', 1518116479, 0, '$bet - $crit ', '$pieces[0]', '$pieces[1]', 0, 10, 0, 'N', 0, 0, '0.00', 'N', 0)";

        mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die ("ERROR: " .mysqli_error($connection) . " (query was $sql)");




    }

    $i++; //increment index

}


mysqli_close($connection);
```